The file cannot be removed even though it is included in the .gitignore list
I have a Flutter project that initially did not have a .gitignore file. After adding the .gitignore file and cleaning up with the following commands:
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "fixed untracked files"

It worked perfectly at first, until my Flutter project built the application for Android. Then, several files in the gradle folder, which had previously been included in the .gitignore, reappeared.

I ran the commands above again, and the files disappeared, but when building the apk again, they reappeared.
.gitignore:
# Do not remove or rename entries in this file, only add new ones
# See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/128635 for more context.

# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.lock
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# Visual Studio Code related
.classpath
.project
.settings/
.vscode/*

# Flutter repo-specific
/bin/cache/
/bin/internal/bootstrap.bat
/bin/internal/bootstrap.sh
/bin/mingit/
/dev/benchmarks/mega_gallery/
/dev/bots/.recipe_deps
/dev/bots/android_tools/
/dev/devicelab/ABresults*.json
/dev/docs/doc/
/dev/docs/api_docs.zip
/dev/docs/flutter.docs.zip
/dev/docs/lib/
/dev/docs/pubspec.yaml
/dev/integration_tests/**/xcuserdata
/dev/integration_tests/**/Pods
/packages/flutter/coverage/
version
analysis_benchmark.json

# packages file containing multi-root paths
.packages.generated

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
pubspec.lock
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
**/generated_plugin_registrant.dart
.packages
.pub-preload-cache/
.pub-cache/
.pub/
build/
flutter_*.png
linked_*.ds
unlinked.ds
unlinked_spec.ds

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
.gradle/
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
**/android/key.properties
*.jks

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/ephemeral
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# macOS
**/Flutter/ephemeral/
**/Pods/
**/macos/Flutter/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift
**/macos/Flutter/ephemeral
**/xcuserdata/

# Windows
**/windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
**/windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.h
**/windows/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake

# Linux
**/linux/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
**/linux/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.h
**/linux/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake

# Coverage
coverage/

# Symbols
app.*.symbols

# Exceptions to above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
!/dev/ci/**/Gemfile.lock
!.vscode/settings.json
.fvmrc
.fvm
android/.gradle/**/executionHistory/executionHistory.bin
android/.gradle/**/executionHistory/executionHistory.lock
android/.gradle/**/fileHashes/fileHashes.bin
android/.gradle/**/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock
android/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup/buildOutputCleanup.lock
android/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup/outputFiles.bin


The same commands have also been run, and git removed those 6 files. However, when building the Android files, those files reappeared.

What exactly is showing those files? It looks like it's from some IDE. Perhaps its configuration is to blame?

The text editor I use is VSCode.
It seems that .gitignore does not truly ignore the selected files/folders, but instead treats them as the latest changes or new files (because they appear when building the application).

To debug a .gitignore issue: if one of said files shows up, run git check-ignore -v path/to/file
